# starts sometimes, other times either nothing or one click when turning it over Mazda 626 special 5 speed 1998

Tags: electrical, starting, car

Question.. what could the clicking be,.I checked for loose wires/plugs and a plug was loose on the alternator, it started after pushing that in, but now still starts when it wants, how do i check out what the actual prob is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be the started motor needs refurbishing, could be the small wire to the solenoid is not making a good contact. Could be the solenoid. 
could be the battery voltage is too low and there is not enough power to actually start the car.

A trip to an auto electrician for diagnosis will be worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  A lot of information there, no so much punctuation.

In any case, I'm *kinda* thinking the "click" is the starter solenoid, which has some burned contacts or is otherwise shot, such that it isn't acting like the "relay" it should and directing the high current to the starter motor windings.

The other possibility is that the starter motor has a so-called "dead spot", which results in the same thing, but might be able to be diagnosed from solenoid failure by the following method:

When you get a "Click but no start", whack on the side of the starter with a hammer (if you can reach it) several times, not like you hate it like your ex-wife's mother-in-law, but like you want to teach it a gentle lesson.  So stronger than a tap, but actually less force than you would use to drive a 12 penny nail.

(If you hit the starter and stuff breaks off, you're hitting too hard.)

This may or may not be easily doable.  And it doesn't matter much, because the utimate solution is going to be replaceing the starter/solenoid assembly in either case.  There are *some* rebuildable solenoids out there (older Toyota) if you have a source for the parts and the knowledge (and you are old and cheap and live under a bridge)  but for the *rest* of you, just get a new starter.

Connections are important; so is "OCV" (open circuit voltage) of the battery.  Use a meter to check battery voltage while just sitting there, and while cranking.  You should see 12.4-12.6 volts just with the hood open, and perhaps
8-9 volts while cranking.  If the voltage doesn't drop *signifigantly* while cranking, that's a sign that the solenoid is bad (Scenario #1) or there's a starter "dead-spot" (Scenario #2).

Either way, the solution is starter replacement.  Or living under a bridge... but tolls are tought to collect these days and I'd advise against it.